# how to link an existing user in odoo with a pos entry?

Tags: rust, odoo, xml-rpc

I have a user in the partner model that I was able to create via rust language.
Now, I have to link a user's ID from the res.partner model to the entry in the pos (Point of sale) model where the partner ID is a manyToOne field.

I'm using the xmlrpc crate to make the XMLRPC call to odoo to save the data. Here's what I have till now:

```
se std::collections::btree_map::IntoValues;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::error::Error;
use std::{collections::HashMap, env};
use xmlrpc::http::{build_headers, check_response};
use xmlrpc::{Request, Transport, Value};

//Somewhere in a function below
let mut body = BTreeMap::new();

    let mut partner_id_vec = BTreeMap::new();

    // trying to create that manyToMany field for saving to odoo.
    partner_id_vec.insert("3".to_string(), Value::Int(625));
    
    // Creating the final struct for sending to the XMLRPC call, this works
    body.insert("partner_id".to_string(), Value::Struct(partner_id_vec));
    body.insert("amount_paid".to_string(), Value::Double(2000.00));
    body.insert("amount_return".to_string(), Value::Double(0.00));
    body.insert("amount_tax".to_string(), Value::Double(0.00));
    body.insert("amount_total".to_string(), Value::Double(2000.00));
    body.insert("name".to_string(), Value::from("jane doe"));

    let order_val_str = Value::Array(vec![Value::Struct(body)]);

    println!("order_val_str: {:?}", order_val_str);

    let save_request = Request::new("execute_kw")
        .arg("db name")
        .arg(request_result.unwrap())
        .arg("My API key".to_string())
        .arg("pos.order")
        .arg("create")
        .arg(order_val_str);

    println!("save_request: {:?}", save_request);

    let result = save_request.call_url("https://my.odoo.com/xmlrpc/2/object");
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just the wrong opcode, "3" is delete/unlink. To create a relation its either "0" or "4".

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command

```
(4, id, 0)
```

Comment: Yes, that seems like the way to go, but I haven't figured out the data structure to be created in rust for accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0):

The `partner_id` field is of type `Many2one` and it expects an integer not a dict, you should see the following error message in the log:

```
ERROR: can't adapt type 'dict'
```

The `session_id` field is mandatory:

```
/addons/point_of_sale/models/pos_order.py", line 415, in create
session = self.env['pos.session'].browse(values['session_id'])
KeyError: 'session_id'
```

Like `partner_id` Odoo will expect an integer.

To ptovide the `partner_id` field value, use the following:

```
body.insert("partner_id".to_string(), Value::Int(625));
```